# How to stop IE displaying image from desktop drag

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I've written a little jQuery function to accept images dragged from the user's desktop, works fine in Chrome but not IE. In IE it just displays the image in the browser as if the `event.preventDefault()` doesn't exist. I cannot find a fix to prevent this, here is the simplified code that isn't working in IE:

```
   $("#imgUploadArea").bind('drop', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //doesn't work 
        return false;       //doesn't work 

        //doesn't work 
        var ev = event || window.event;
        ev.preventDefault();        

        return false;       

    }).bind('dragenter', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('greenBorder');
    }).bind("dragleave", function(e){
        $(this).removeClass('greenBorder');
    });
```

If any one could shed some light on how to stop IE showing the image in the browser when dragged from the desktop that would be a great help.

Comment: IE9 and below i was catering for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you can see [here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie09.html), IE 9 does not support drag'n'drop.

as you can see [here](http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie10.html), IE 10 supports it.

so unless you use IE 10 you are not able to use drag'n'drop in vanilla IE.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, shame i might have to get the user to get Chrome or update to IE10 which is bad. Or do some kind logic to test if IE and use a different upload method to get the image name.

Comment: @dezza The more appropriate response would be to gracefully degrade to a file-upload form ;)